# BMI in Java implementation

Tags: java

I had the task to implement from UML Diagramm the classes and attributes

My code :

```
public abstract class Human {

    
    private String name; 
    private String firstname; 
    private int  age;
    private Gender gender;
    private String adress;
    private int height;
    private int weight;
    
    public enum Gender {
        MALE, FEMALE
    }

    public enum BMI {
        NORMAL, UNDERWEIGHT, OVERWEIGHT
    }
    
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
        
    
    private String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    private void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    private void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    private int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    private void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    private Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    private void setGender(Gender gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    private String getAdress() {
        return adress;
    }

    private void setAdress(String adress) {
        this.adress = adress;
    }

    private int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    private void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    private int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    private void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

}
```

My another task is:

BMI() is calculated with the following formula:
body weight (in kg) / (height (in m))^2
When calculating I have to watch out for units. Use Math.round to round the result correctly. I may also use Math.pow here.

My idea was:

```
public static long bmi(double weightInKg, double heightInMeters) {
    return Math.round(weightInKg / Math.pow(heightInMeters, 2));
}
```

But my problem is the Signature from the method should be: `BMI(): double` and mine is `BMI(): double double`

So how can I improve my code ?

Comment: Sorry Jim Garrison

Comment: Why do you think it should be `BMI():double`?  Body Mass Index is a function of both weight and height, so any method that calculates it must take ***two*** parameters.

Comment: Because It is stated in my assignment BMI(): double

Comment: I just wanted to know is there another option with the signature BMI(): double to implement BMI

Comment: That does not make sense.  I believe that syntax means it _returns_ double, which does make sense.  You may have misunderstood the assignment.  Talk to your teacher.

Comment: I have an UML Diagramm given:                    Method:BMI(): double

Comment: Talk to your teacher.  A method to calculate BMI ***must*** have two parameters because BMI is a function of two numbers.

Comment: Regardless of the instructions, your code actually has as a long, not a double (and BMI is not in the range needed by a long anyway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UML, if the method takes parameters, it would be written as `BMI(arg1, arg2)` or maybe `BMI(arg1: double, arg2: double)`.

The colon + type on the method call is the return type, not the parameters (as you seem to think of saying `double double`)

Besides that, you have height and weight as fields, so your method does need parameters (as the UML states), and it needs to return a double rather than a long, and not be static.

```
public double BMI() {
    return getWeight() / Math.pow(getHeight(), 2);
}
```